# PayPal Developer Sandbox API Credentials do not provide username, password and signature

Tags: laravel, paypal-sandbox, omnipay

Trying to setup an app with a sandbox account on PayPal. I already had a Business account with PayPal and have created a new application under the Sandbox.

I am provided with 3 credentials by PayPal:

- `Sandbox account` which has the appearance of an email address
- `Client ID`
- `Secret`

However, using Omnipay with Laravel and it asks me for Username, Password and Signature in the config/env. I have some legacy prod credentials which look nothing like those provided by PayPal above, so can't even make an educated guess.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

- client ID+secret are API credentials [from a REST App](https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/applications/sandbox) , which if for sandbox mode will be tied to a particular sandbox account when the app is created
- For the old classic NVP/SOAP API Username/Password/Signature credentials, go directly to [the sandbox account list](https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/accounts) and in manage accounts (...) select View/Edit account, second tab.